# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getEntityAttribute()

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have this strange issue.
It was not happening before and after I pulled form github , 
when I send json responses and send and eloquent object with it, it gives me this error. Presumably when the model gets serialized.
I've tried to parse it with json_encode but still the same issue.
I don't know whats going on , is it the issue of the json_encode or a problem with the eloquent model.It's related to all the models because all of them return the same error when i try to parse them to json.
**It was ok before** but now I don't know what went wrong.
I've compared commits to see the differences but still no luck.
I could not find anything that might have caused this issue so I'm guessing it is the fault of an nontracked file so I reinstalled the dependencies again through composer install still no luck.
When I reverse to the last commit it works fine so the theory of the untracked files is rubish.

Has anyone have any idea ? 
I'm going nuts over this.

```
This is the stacktrace form when it starts to convert to json : 
[2018-04-18 14:22:53] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getEntityAttribute() {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::getEntityAttribute() at /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2483)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1288): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->__call('getEntityAttrib...', Array)
#1 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1470): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call('getEntityAttrib...', Array)
#2 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(438): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->__call('getEntityAttrib...', Array)
#3 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(450): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->mutateAttribute('entity', NULL)
#4 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(109): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->mutateAttributeForArray('entity', NULL)
#5 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(970): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->attributesToArray()
#6 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(1611): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->toArray()
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->Illuminate\\Support\\{closure}(Object(App\\AdminActivity))
#8 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(1612): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#9 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(237): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->toArray()
#10 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(970): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->relationsToArray()
#11 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(237): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->toArray()
#12 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(970): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->relationsToArray()
#13 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(999): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->toArray()
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->jsonSerialize()
#15 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php(71): json_encode(Array, 0)
#16 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/JsonResponse.php(50): Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse->setData(Array)
#17 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php(31): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse->__construct(Array, 200, Array)
#18 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(83): Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse->__construct(Array, 200, Array, 0)
#19 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-restaurant/app/Http/Controllers/BaseController.php(19): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->json(Array)
#20 /home/marlind/PhpstormProjects/ital-
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a problem with getting custom attribute. You can do that in a model by writing get{name}Attribute. You didn't provide us with any code so it's hard to point an error.

Comment: You were a great help sir. I found something similar that I thought was not related to any of the requests but somehow it was inportant.

Comment: I have a Ticket model belongsTo user & user has getFullnameAttribute(). But I've got this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getUser.fullnameAttribute()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but found it when searching for a problem I encountered.

Given that the stack trace is similar to mine I think the information and solution I found could shed more light on the matter.

Here's a link to Laravel's documentation about mutators as array:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-object-and-collection-casting

For me the problem was when doing ->toArray() on a model that had attribute mutators.
Solved it by adding the following to the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'entity' => AsArrayObject::class,
];
```